# nohup not updating nohup.out

Tags: linux, nohup

Boiling down to the smallest problem here is a simple python script that I want to run using nohup on linux. I run it using the following (on linux):

```
 nohup python test.py &
```

The command seems to just not do anything, nothing is appended to nohup.out. If I run it without the '&' the output shows correctly on the terminal window. What am I missing?

```
 import time

 def test():
   while(True):
     print "Woke up!"
     time.sleep(5)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: Try `sys.stdout.flush()` and see if it works.

Answer (score 6):

Try running it with the command `nohup python -u test.py &`.  This should make the output unbuffered.

You can make the script executable by adding a bang path as the first line with the `-u` option.  Your will also need to set the executable bit with the command `chmod +x test.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
import time
....
```

You can then run it as `nohup test.py &`.

Answer (score 0):

Block-based I/O buffering, I'd guess. What happens if you set the Python equivalent of `setvbuf(3)` line-based or unbuffered output on standard out?